# Successfully vs successfuly

Tags: differences, american-english, british-english

I tried to go through several sites, but none of them explained if there is any difference or if any of these variants are not valid (or *"not English"*). At the beginning, I was using the translation dictionary [slovnik.cz](http://slovnik.cz) to translate from my native language (Czech) and both options were shown as possible:

[image]

Usually, I don't find two "same looking" words both valid and formally valid.

Written as (different in count of `l`s):

- **Successfully**
- **Successfuly**

Questions:

- Is there any difference between them?
- Is one variation more formal (or valid) then the other?
- Is there any difference between American and British English in this case?

Comment: What language are you translating from? Which translation dictionary are you using?

Comment: I have been using slovnik.cz and translating from Czech language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google:

[image: Let me Google that for you.]

from spellchecker.net

[image: from https://www.spellchecker.net/misspellings/successfuly]

Answer (score -1):

"Successfully" is correct. "Successfuly" is a spelling error.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but until You provide some references from this or that source, this seems more like an opinion then the "fact".

Comment: It is not an opinion. I happen to know how to speak English.